# Calculate Duration Between Two TimeStamps in two rows SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, difference

I want to calculate the duration between two rows like Between Start DateTime of a fault and End DateTime for reporting.

I Googled and [found](http://dba-datascience.com/calculate-date-difference-of-2-consecutive-rows-of-a-column-tsql/) we can do that using below:

```
SELECT  TagEventId,TagID,ServerResponse,FaultCode, ReaderID as DeviceID,EventTimeStamp as startDateTime, pDataDate as EnDateTime,DATEDIFF(minute, pDataDate, eventtimestamp) as Duration
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                LAG(eventtimestamp) OVER (ORDER BY eventtimestamp) pDataDate
        FROM    tagevents where readerid=25 and tagid='0'
        ) q
```

And it is returning result as below:

[image]

What we are displaying in Report.. There is one start Time of a fault which will have faultCode and TagID=0. Application will hit to API to check again after every 10 minutes.. if this is returning proper response with FaultCode=0.

So there could be multiple records between a Fault start Date Time and Fault Time End Date.

I want to get the difference between these two in Duration Column and I have to display only one record for each Fault that will have startDateTime, EndDateTime and Duration of Fault.

Please help me.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between multiple faults (let's say same device and fault code occurs multiple time)

Comment: look for "sql server data islands", you need to "merge" consecutive errors into one period/island and calculate the datediff(IslandStart, IslandEnd)